# Disable pagination animation

Tags: javafx, pagination, javafx-2

I'm trying to disable the `Pagination` control animation using JavaFX. I could not find any precise info on how to do that. I know some controls have the `setAnimated(false)` method, but this one doesn't.

Maybe there is a solution via CSS styling or via the Skin interface, but I'm kinda new to JavaFX

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For JavaFX 2.2, the pagination animation is going to be a little tough to disable.

As you note there is no public API to disable the animation (and there isn't anything in CSS).  What you will need to is create your own skin and assign that skin to the pagination control.

To do this use the default [JavaFX 2.2 pagination skin](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/master/rt/file/tip/javafx-ui-controls/src/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/PaginationSkin.java) as a base and edit it so that it doesn't do animations.  If you rename your custom pagination skin to another package (e.g. org.acme.javafx.scene.control.skin), then you can specify that new skin via assigning a css stylesheet to your app which includes the following rule:

```
.pagination {
    -fx-skin: "org.acme.javafx.scene.control.skin.PaginationSkin";
}
```

Apart from the difficulty of initial implementation for a new JavaFX user (which is rather significant) another serious downside to this approach is that in JavaFX 2.2, the skin API is not public, so when JavaFX 8 is released where the skin api is public, your changes probably won't work, so you will need to recode them for JavaFX 8. The reason your changes won't continue to work for JavaFX 8 is that the `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase` class your custom pagination skin needs to derive from will have moved to something like `javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase` to become public API.

So I'd suggest living with the Pagination animation for now unless you really need to get rid of it.

There is currently a a request against the [JavaFX runtime issue tracker](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com) to allow disabling animation in the Pagination control.  See [RT-26439 Pagination: Animation of page flip should be deactivatable](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-26439).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. I've created my own PaginationSkin based on the one I got from the master branch in the hg repo of OpenJFX 2.2.2. Here it is: https://gist.github.com/4626632. It's really basic right now, but I'll improve it later.

Comment: JavaFX bugtracker link for this issue has changed to a new bug system: [JDK-8090977 Pagination: Animation of page flip should be deactivatable](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090977)