# Disable pagination animation for javafx 8

Tags: pagination, javafx-8

I am trying to convert the solution from stackoverflow thread:
[Disable pagination animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143147/javafx-pagination-animation)

it is too complicated to do it with JavaFX 8 because Utils is and other classes like SkinBase have changed with different arguments.

does anyone have a working example with pagination animation disabled for JavaFX8 ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, 
I did it!
using  Gabriel Féron answer from : https://gist.github.com/gferon/4626632
I've translated it to JavaFX8:
first create an -fx-skin on css of scene you want to disable pagination animation:

```
.pagination {
    -fx-border-color:  #0E5D79;
     -fx-skin: "com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.PaginationSkinErez";
}
```

then:
use the following attached class instead of original PaginationSkin.
I can't attach the class here has 5000+ lines. can someone help with it ?

Comment: for attaching your class, create a git gist first, then put gist url here( like Gabriel Féron). i need your class. please attach it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach. Instead of using pagination's pageFactory, change the page directly using the currentPageIndexProperty's listener. See the link for more details.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49004733/6034157