# how can I disable default scene animation(flip) in javafx 8?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a Main screen and multiple sub-screens. when I change the screen or return to main screen, default scene pagination of JavaFx-8 (flip) animated. how can I disable this default behavior?

Comment: I found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143147/disable-pagination-animation , but that isn't a solution for javafx-8 .

Comment: What do you mean by "changing screen"? Is it changing `Scene` in single `Stage`? By default there isn't any animation during such action. I recommend you to edit your question with more details and snippet of your code which can show your problem.

Comment: here's the post that's a javafx8 solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31052109/disable-pagination-animation-for-javafx-8